# htaccess redirection to one file for one domain and another file for another alias domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains going to a vhost

example.com thisismyexample.com << this is an alias of the first one. It has got his own vhosts which is a symbolic link of the first one.

I need different behavior for each one so I'd like to redirect as:

if request comes for `example.com -> example.com/index.php`

if request comes for `thisismyexample.com -> thisismyexample.com/admin.php`

Both files index.php and admin.php are on the same directory which is my document root. At the moment there's a `REQUEST_FILENAME` rule and everything goes to index.php

I would try with redirectmatch but would like some opinions first

```
RedirectMatch ^example.com/$ http://example.com/index.php

RedirectMatch ^thisismyexample.com/$ http://thisismyexample.com/admin.php
```

Is this possible using htacces? If so, how would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond` that checks the host-header:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thisismyexample.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/admin.php [R,L]
```

Comment: Will test it later on tonight but yeah that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!